# Problem with a variable undefined in a mat dialog text in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I created a dialog using angular in order to collect a information and save it on my back-end.

The problem is when i will send it to my back-end, using my post method, the variable of the coment stay undefined. The variable in question is:

> val: " "

this is my dialog ts  file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core'; import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog'; import { IstManagementService } from './../../core/services/ist-management.service'; import { ReasonpopupService } from 'ClientApp/app/core/services/reasonpopup.service';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-reasonpopup',   templateUrl: './reasonpopup.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./reasonpopup.component.css'] }) export class ReasonpopupComponent implements OnInit {
     val : " " 
 
    /* reason2 : string = this.reason */
  
     onSubmit() { this.MatDialogRef.close(this.val); }
  

 
  
     getValue(val:string){
    console.log(val)
      }


  constructor(
    private istManagementService: IstManagementService,
    public MatDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ReasonpopupComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private shared:ReasonpopupService,
    

    ) { }
     ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.shared.setMessage(this.val)   }

  reason :string   closeDialog() {
    this.MatDialogRef.close(false);   }
          
}
```

my html file:

```
<div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <mat-icon id="close-icon" (click)="closeDialog()">close</mat-icon>
    <span class="content-span full-width">{{ data.message }}</span>
  </div>
  <form #userForm="ngForm">
  <div class="input-reason">
    
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill" [style.width.px]=420 style="padding-bottom: 100px;" >
        <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>

        <textarea
        [(ngModel)]="val"
          type="text"
          ngModel class="form-control"
          required
          #text
          minlength="3"
          class="form-control"
          name="tx"
          matInput
          placeholder="please describe the reason"
        ></textarea>
        <span *ngIf="text.invalid && text.touched" class="error">input the reason</span>
      </mat-form-field>
   
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button id="no-button" [mat-dialog-close]="false">NO</button>
  <button
    mat-raised-button
    [disabled]="userForm.invalid"
    id="yes-button"
    (click)="onSubmit()" 
    (click)="getValue(text.value)"
    [mat-dialog-close]="data.text"
    cdkFocusInitial
  >
    YES
  </button>

    </form>
</div>
```

The method where i pass my variable as argument on the other component that have the post method

```
saveRow() {
        let addRowsRequest = {
            IstValues: this.dataSource.data.filter(r => r.editing)
            
        };
        console.log(this.val)
        this.istManagementService.postRecord(this.inputTable, addRowsRequest, this.val).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                console.log(this.dataSource.data.filter(r => r.editing));
                this.dataSource.data.push(this.dataSource.data.filter(r => r.editing));
                this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
            }
        )
    }
```

My setter and getter service that i created to share the variable between the components

```
mport { ReasonpopupComponent } from './../../tasks/reasonpopup/reasonpopup.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReasonpopupService {
val:string
  constructor(private messageDialog: MatDialog) { }

  openReasonDialog(msg: string) {
    return this.messageDialog.open(ReasonpopupComponent, {
      width: '570px',
      panelClass: 'confirm-dialog-container',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { message: msg }
    })
  }

  setMessage(data: string){
    this.val=data
    console.log(this.val)
  }

  getMessage(){
    return this.val
  }


}
```

and finally, my service that contain all the CRUD methods

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ISTGenericResponse } from '../../pages/ist-management/ist-generic-response';
import { environment } from 'ClientApp/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IstManagementService {


    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


    public getGenericStaticTablesFiltered(inputTable: string, inputKey: string, inputValue: string, inputComparison: string): Observable<ISTGenericResponse> {
        var filter = "";
        if (inputKey && inputValue) {
            filter = "?key=" + inputKey + "&value=" + inputValue + "&comparison=" + inputComparison;
            return this.httpClient.get<ISTGenericResponse>(environment.apiRoot + "/StaticTable/Filter/" + inputTable + filter);
        }
        else {
            return this.httpClient.get<ISTGenericResponse>(environment.apiRoot + "/StaticTable/" + inputTable);
        }
    }
    message:string
    setMessage(data: string){
        this.message=data
    }
    getMessage(){
        return this.getMessage
    }
   
    postRecord(inputTable: string, addRecord: any,  message:any ) {
        return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiRoot + "/StaticTable/Add/" + inputTable, addRecord,  message);
    }

    deleteRecord(inputTable: string, deleteRecord: any) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
        return this.httpClient.request('delete', environment.apiRoot + "/StaticTable/Delete/" + inputTable, { body: deleteRecord, headers: headers });
    }

    editRecord(inputTable: string, editRecord: any): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
        return this.httpClient.request('put', environment.apiRoot + "/StaticTable/Update/" + inputTable, { body: editRecord, headers: headers, });
```

}

}

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this code, you are calling `this.shared.setMessage(this.val)` inside the `ngOnInit()` method of `ReasonpopupComponent`

which will always be undefined because `ngOnInit()` is only called on the initialization of the component before the user inputs any data.

what you need to do is to move `this.shared.setMessage(this.val)` inside `onSubmit()` method, so in the end it looks like this

```
export class ReasonPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  val = '';

  constructor(
    private istManagementService: IstManagementService,
    public MatDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ReasonPopupComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private shared:ReasonpopupService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.shared.setMessage(this.val);
    this.MatDialogRef.close(this.val);

  }
  
  closeDialog() {
    this.MatDialogRef.close(false);
  }
}
```

what would be even better, if your "other component" is the one opening the pop-up, you can make use of angular material dialog subscriber. as you see in `onSubmit()` method `this.matDialogRef.close(this.val)`is already called with the value. all you need to do is to subscribe to it on the "other component" like so.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    });
```